# List files, directories and executables in current directory

Tags: shell, files, directory, executable

I have php shell and I have function that do just that (but it give me error when I call `scandir($path)` function because of restriction in php), so I need to use my bash shell to do the same.

It can be one command that list all 3 things separated by some delimiters or they can be 3 commands.

What is the best way to do that? The only thing I can think of is `find` executed 3 times with `-maxdepth 1` and some options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `find`, you could call:

```
find /some/dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f \
  \( -executable -printf 'X%p\0' -o -printf 'F%p\0' \) -o \
  -type d -printf 'D%p\0'
```

The output will be a NUL-delimited (NUL is the only  character that may not appear in a file path) list of records, the first letter of which identifies the *type* (`X`, `F`, `D` for executable regular files, other regular files, directories).

For symlinks, if you want to consider the type of the target of the symlink instead, use `-xtype` instead of `-type` above. `-executable` returns files that are executable by the process that runs that find command. Other types of files (fifo, socket, doors, devices...) are ignored. The `.` and `..` directory entries are also ignored.

Comment: Great, too bad it don't show special files.

Comment: @jcubic, just add a `-o -type x` for any other type of file you want included, and/or `-o -printf 'O%p\0'` for all other types of files.

Comment: This work for all `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \( -type f -executable -printf 'X%p\0' \)  -o -type d -printf 'D%p\0' -o -not -type d -printf 'F%p\0'`

Comment: @jcubic, putting a symlink, especially a symlink to a directory or a socket in the same category as a regular file does not necessarily make sense. Depends exactly what you mean by _file_. Directories are files as well by some definitions of _file_. No point in using `-not` when `!` is shorter and standard.

Comment: symlink to dir should be dir, but all other can be just files. How can I test if symlink point to directory, does your command do that?

Comment: @jcubic, as I said, use `-xtype` to test for the type after resolving symlinks.